# iOS Local Notification with Different Content each time

Tags: ios, background, notifications

I'd like some help on how to do something like this:

a) User enters a collection of strings into my app
b) User sets a preference for how often to post one of those strings as a notification
c) User "turns on" notifications
       Within this code, it would set a notification to occur x number of seconds in the future based on what the user entered in the preference mentioned in b) above.
d) User exits app
e) At the future point in time, the notification is triggered.

---- I have up to the above figured out -----

Now, when that notification is triggered, I want to automatically set up a new notification that has an alertBody the next string in the array (or whatever structure I use) that the user entered in a) above. I'd prefer this to happen without the user having to launch my app and ideally, if the prior notification has not been dismissed, this new notification should replace the old one (or perhaps show up in the list of notifications).

How do you do something like this in iOS "in the background" without requiring the user to open the app to schedule and configure the next notification?

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into `NSUserDefaults`. It's generally a straightforward approach for relatively low-complexity persistent storage requirements (other more complex alternatives being local file, Core Data, SQLite, or web service). Based on your description, I'd setup the notifications when the app gets backgrounded (i.e. App Delegate). Take note that your app only has 64 scheduled local notifications to work with, so you'll have to setup a 64 cycle `for` loop which then iterates through your array of strings and schedules a notification for each. If your array of strings is longer than 64, I believe your best bet is to hope that your users will open up your app within 64 notifications firing so you can setup the next batch. You'll need to get creative to find a way to track which string in your array you were up to at that point, perhaps doing some math based on when the last batch of notifcations was setup (can also be stored in `NSUserDefaults`) and the configured interval between each notification.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @EricBrown Edited my answer with more details on where `NSUserDefaults` may come handy.

Comment: @jww No critique or clarification, I guess sometimes I assume whatever's in my head is apparent. :] Edited my answer, hopefully it's more helpful!

Comment: It is more helpful, but I'm still not quite there. A parallel: on the Android platform, I can use a Service to run in the background to do this. I use the Android alarms to fire the service on the interval the user selects. When the service launches (silently in the background), it can determine which string was used last and then post a new notification (and accompanying Intent that causes this cycle to continue). Does iOS have anything like this arrangement?

Comment: @Greg Nope unfortunately iOS is quite limited in what can be done in the background. You can monitor motion and location, run audio or VOIP, bluetooth connectivity, etc, but you can't arbitrarily launch an app based on time. The closest thing to achieving what you intend would be to use a Push notification as a trigger, though it's definitely not trivial.